# Using set to update graphs in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm trying to update new values to a function using the 'set' function.

Here is the code:

```
daq_object = analoginput('winsound');
chan = addchannel(daq_object,1);
x=[10];
num_samples = 1000;
axes(handles.axes1);
plot_handle=surf(T,F,10*log10(P),'edgecolor','none'); 
axis tight; 
view(0,90);
xlabel('Time (Seconds)'); ylabel('Hz');

 set(daq_object,'SamplesPerTrigger',inf,'SamplesAcquiredFcnCount',num_samples,...
    'SamplesAcquiredFcn',{@update_plot,handles});

function update_plot(handles)

data = getdata(daq_object,num_samples);
[S,F,T,P] = spectrogram(data,256,250,256,1E3);

    set(plot_handle,'YData',T,F,P); % ERROR WITH THIS, UPDATING THE VARIABLES. 

end
```

The error is that, I don't know how to update multiple variables in a function. for one variable ex:

```
h=plot(zeros(100,2));
for i=1:20
    set(h,'Ydata',rand(10,1));
    drawnow;
end
```

but here I need to update the T,F and P values. How can I use SET to do that?

I tried:

```
set(plot_handle,'YData',T,F,P);
```

but thats just giving me errors.

Comment: Your example uses `analoginput` from the Data Acquisition toolbox.  Since many people who might answer you (including myself) don't have access to this toolbox, could your provide an example which uses base MATLAB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set` takes name-value pairs, that is, after the first variable (which is a handle to a figure or some axes), the arguments need to alternate `name of variable`, then `value to assign to that variable`.

In your example that failed you have three consecutive values (`T`, `F` and `P`) without names in between.

Comment: so i should edit `set(plot_handle,'YData',T,F,P);` to `set(plot_handle,'XData',T,'YData',F,'ZData',P);`